# Context is NULL with SDL_CreateWindowFrom Win32

Tags: sdl2

There is a `VC ++ Win32` project. It connected the library sdl, follows CreateWindowW I have written

```
 SDL_Window* w = SDL_CreateWindowFrom(hWnd);
 //  SDL_WindowFlags(SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
   SDL_GLContext glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(w);
   if (glcontext == NULL)OutputDebugString("null");
```

But my glcontext == NULL and `SDL_GetError` returns  `The specified window isn't an OpenGL window`

But if I use `SDL_CreateWindow`, context turns out successfully

Even after the creation of the window using

```
static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
       sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), // strcut size 
       1,                              // Version number
       PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |    // Flags, draw to a window,
       PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL, // use OpenGL
       PFD_TYPE_RGBA,          // RGBA pixel values
       24,                     // 24-bit color
       0, 0, 0,                // RGB bits & shift sizes.
       0, 0, 0,                // Don't care about them
       0, 0,                   // No alpha buffer info
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0,          // No accumulation buffer
       32,                     // 32-bit depth buffer
       0,                      // No stencil buffer
       0,                      // No auxiliary buffers
       PFD_MAIN_PLANE,         // Layer type
       0,                      // Reserved (must be 0)
       0,                      // No layer mask
       0,                      // No visible mask
       0                       // No damage mask
   };



   // Did We Get A Device Context?
   hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

   PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);

   SetPixelFormat(hDC, PixelFormat, &pfd);

   // Are We Able To Get A Rendering Context?
   hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);

   // Try To Activate The Rendering Context
   wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
   ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);


   SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);


   SDL_Window* w = SDL_CreateWindowFrom(hWnd);
   SDL_GLContext glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(w);
   if (glcontext == NULL)OutputDebugString("null");
```

Can not get context. How correctly get the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=9578&sid=090b706304f1829218c9c0f6887cce86) thread it seems that creating OpenGL contexts from foreign windows isn't currently supported in SDL.

> We can either always set the OPENGL flag for foreign windows, allowing you to try to create a context and let it fail if it's not compatible, or we can add a new API, something like SDL_CreateOpenGLWindowFrom()

According to various different threads it seems that there is no OpenGL initialization code in `SDL_CreateWindowFrom`, so OpenGL context initialization won't work with that method. If you are building your own SDL binaries, you might want to consider modifying the `SDL_CreateWindowFrom` function by adding the correct `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` flag to the correct place in that method. It seems to be what people experiencing this same problem have done.

Why are you not using SDL for window creation? Letting SDL handle the windowing makes it easier for you to develop, and it will also make your project more cross-platform. When you create the window using `SDL_CreateWindow()`, just remember to pass in the `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` flag to the creation, and then you should be able to create your OpenGL context just fine.

Comment: Because I want to use OpenGL with Win32 GUI

Comment: Okay. In that case, you have two good options IMHO: You either modify SDL to initialize OpenGL in `SDL_CreateWindowFrom` or you ask SDL to create the window, and get the window handle from SDL, and perform your GUI on that handle.

Comment: But how can I add Win32 GUI to the SDL window?

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in the GDSE [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) to keep the comment section more clean.

Comment: You actually did answer the question, but not sure if SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL is enough to make it compatible. My SDL_GL_CreateContext now just crash.

Comment: Check what `SDL_GetError()` says, as that flag should make it work.

Answer (score 3):

So I made it here looking for help on this, and actually managed to get the idea for a fix. Not sure if too late to help anyone who posted here though but there it goes anyway :)

After diving in SDL 2.0.3's source, I found out that one can first create a "dummy" OpenGL window which SDL will look up at when setting up the foreign window. To make this work, you need to set the `SDL_HINT_VIDEO_WINDOW_SHARE_PIXEL_FORMAT` hint to point at the dummy window before calling `SDL_CreateWindowFrom` - more info on that here (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_VIDEO_WINDOW_SHARE_PIXEL_FORMAT).

After creating the foreign window, you might want to destroy the dummy, but that will make `SDL_GL_CreateContext` crash when called, since SDL keeps track of how many OpenGL windows have been created in order to unload the GL library when all are gone, but won't increase the ref count when creating a foreign OpenGL window. There are 2 fixes for this:

- Just keep the dummy window alive and hidden during the whole execution (simplest approach, and probably the best)
- Add the refcount increase to SDL (which was my choice)

If you want to go the latter way you would need to make the block starting at line 354 in file src/video/windows/SDL_windowswindow.c look like this:

```
// If the otherWindow has SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL set, set it for the new window as well
if (otherWindow->flags & SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL)
{
    window->flags |= SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL;
    if(!WIN_GL_SetPixelFormatFrom(_this, otherWindow, window)) {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        SDL_GL_LoadLibrary(NULL);
    }
}
```

And here's my code for creating the foreign window:

```
SDL_Window* pSampleWin = SDL_CreateWindow("", 0, 0, 1, 1, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN);

char sBuf[32];
sprintf_s<32>(sBuf, "%p", pSampleWin);

SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_VIDEO_WINDOW_SHARE_PIXEL_FORMAT, sBuf);
mpWindow = SDL_CreateWindowFrom(aInitVars.mpExternalWindowHandle);
SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_VIDEO_WINDOW_SHARE_PIXEL_FORMAT, nullptr);

SDL_DestroyWindow(pSampleWin);
```

Note: I haven't dealt with releasing the library reference here, might be worth looking into.